# Align image label with bars in polar Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've created an inverted polar chart which maps bar categories with an image (I've simplified it with a static image in this example):

[image: Image of a polar bar chart with red box images as labels]

What I want to do is perfectly align the label images so that the height is the same as the height of its corresponding bar, and it's aligned vertically with its corresponding bar.

This should be responsive - i.e. image label should resize when bars do. Essentially, it should look like the bars are 'coming out' of their corresponding image labels.

You can view a JS fiddle with the code in-action here: https://jsfiddle.net/anorlondo/dmqsnvf6/27/

I'll also include the code below:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Highcharts Column Chart</title>
    <!-- Include Highcharts library -->
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart-container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
       var data = [
            { cat: 1, value: 10 },
            { cat: 3, value: 9 },
            { cat: 5, value: 6 },
            { cat: 10, value: 4 }
        ];
        
        
Highcharts.chart('chart-container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                polar: true,
                inverted: true
            },
            colors: ["#A9FFCB", "#B6EEA6",
            "#C0B298", "#A4778B"
            ],
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    pointPadding: 0.1,
                    groupPadding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                max: 11,
                gridLineColor: null,
                series: [{
                    borderWidth: 0
                }],
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: data.map(function(o) { return o.cat; }),
                tickInterval: 1,
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                gridLineColor: null,
                lineWidth: 0,
                labels: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                    return '<img src="https://i.ibb.co/zPJHkJK/ex-img.png"></img>'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: data.map(function(o) { return o.value; })
            }]
        });
```

Comment: Consider using rendered rectangles to achieve this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u3yb8ozs/ - this way allows you to create responsiveness unlike the png's